How to align multiple fields together in fmt?
Is it possible to align multiple fields together?
E.g.,
std::format("{:{}:<12} text", file, line)

to align as
main.cpp:1   text

and not as
main.cpp:   1 text


Yes it is possible, format the file+line to a string first and then format the final ouput using the previously formatted string.  Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but it matches your question (which is not very specific)

The example does not seem to match the question title and description. The accepted answer aligns and pads only a single field (out of many), and no group of fields are treated as "together".

@WeijunZhou I think OP meant, multiple arguments, instead of "multiple fields". The Ques. title has to be therefore reformed, according to the description.


Is it possible to align multiple fields together?

No. But you can combine the fields first, and align the result later.
std::format("{:<12} text\n", std::format("{}:{}", file, line));

This produces
main.cpp:1   text

